# How to revert buffer after magit-checkout?

Tags: magit, revert-buffer, smart-mode-line

I use [smart-mode-line package](https://github.com/Malabarba/smart-mode-line) and I noticed when I change/checkout branches in command line, or in Magit, this is not reflected in the Smart Mode Line. I still see the name of the old branch, while I checked out the other branch.

I need to call `M-x revert-buffer` to see the actual branch reflected in Smart Mode Line.

These option gives me an error, while in documentation I need to supply REVISION in magit-checkout parameter, which is unknown in Emacs Lisp as variable:

```
  (add-function :after (magit-checkout) #'revert-buffer)
```

And this didn't help either:

```
(setq magit-auto-revert-mode t)
```

So I'm running out of ideas. Anyone?

Comment: Your first code fragment should something more like `(advice-add 'magit-checkout :after #'revert-buffer)`

Comment: See [`force-mode-line-update`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Basics.html).

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately. Nevertheless, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 1):

`magit-auto-revert-mode` is a mode and therefore should be enabled by calling the mode function, not by setting the variable. But it is supposed to be enabled by default, so you shouldn't have to do that.

(But you might have disabled this a long time ago, possibly using an old implementation, so it might get disabled for non-obvious reasons. Check your configuration for occurrences not only of `magit-auto-revert-mode`, but also `magit-revert-buffers`, and remove all that.)

For me the buffer information gets automatically updated without any additional configuration and I am using `smart-mode-line` too. So you should proceed by disabling your own customization and all packages not required by `magit` and check whether it works then. If so, proceed by enabling more and more of your packages and customization until it breaks again. This will allow you to narrow the issue down.