# magit-checkout does not update current buffer

Tags: spacemacs, magit

When I checkout an existing remote branch, the current buffer remains on the old branch.
However if I open a new file, that new file is on the checked-out branch.

My current workflow is this:

1. editing file `a.txt`
2. magit-checkout `feature` (`a.txt` exists on `feature`)
3. close `a.txt`
4. open `a.txt`

And the workflow I want to get is this:

1. editing file `a.txt`
2. magit-checkout `feature` (`a.txt` exists on `feature`)
3. `a.txt` is now the version from `feature`

Is there a way to make the current buffer file be checked out on the new branch?

p.s. I'm using Spacemacs, don't know if that matters here.

Comment: I experience this too. I don't have a solution, but I have a workaround that's slightly faster. I have bound `revert-buffer` to `F5`, so instead of closing the buffer and opening another one, I just hit a single key to reload.

Comment: Remember, a buffer is not the same thing as a file. Probably the right way to go about this would be to define some kind of hook that runs after `magit-checkout`, which would identify buffers associated to the repo and run `revert-buffer` on all of them.

Comment: This old question (and answer) are related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/34589/how-to-revert-buffer-after-magit-checkout

Comment: @MTS I saw that but didn't understand it was related, thank you for the pointer.

Comment: I see that Spacemacs (or someone) also enables `Global-Auto-Revert` minor mode... and for some reason after using `revert-buffer` I now see the behavior I originally wanted, without any extra action on my part.  Maybe the auto reverting only happens if magit knows the file exists in both branches.  It's mysterious, but I have a workaround now, so thanks.

Comment: First make sure Magit is up-to-date--I remember there was a bug related to this a while back. Then make sure either `magit-auto-revert-mode` or `global-auto-revert-mode` is enabled. The former should be enabled by default. Make sure one of these modes is enabled before you open a file.

Comment: I want to clarify the question. Does the buffer itself not change, or are you just concerned about the git information displayed in the mode line? The mode line in a buffer will only update automatically if the file underlying that buffer changes. If you want the mode line to update automatically, see this answer: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/48091/6692

Comment: @MTS My question was regarding the buffer itself not changing.  The mode line tells me what version of the file I'm looking at (file A on branch X or file A on branch Y) and that also does not change.

Comment: OK. Well, as tarsius (the author/maintainer of magit) says, as long as `magit-auto-revert-mode` is on, buffers that change should update automatically. You should try to bisect your settings to see if something is interfering with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Disclaimer: I don't know if this is how Magit and Spacemacs actually work, but it fits my hypothesis.)

When you `magit-checkout` a remote branch, magit can't know if the current file you have open in the buffer also exists in the remote branch.  However, `git-checkout` changed the file, so a workaround (pointed out in a comment by [MTS](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/6692/mts)) is to *revert* the file (as in, revert to the version that changed on disk) using `M-x revert-buffer RET`.

Once you've reverted the file once, checking out the previous branch again (or checking out a new branch) will automatically revert the file going forward.

At least, this occurs on my system (Spacemacs with the `Global-Auto-Revert` minor mode enabled).

So the modified workflow is:

1. edit `a.txt`
2. `magit-checkout` remote branch `feature`
3. if the file does not update, force it using `revert-buffer`
4. `a.txt` will be the version from `feature`
5. subsequent checkouts will revert automatically